# Sencha Ext js with Visual Studio ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, extjs

I need to develop application using visual studio, asp.net + c# + MS SQL Server.

I also have to use sencha ext js (MVC) for the UI.

I don't want to use visual studio MVC application. I have to use normal web application.

So I have created a "new website"with "Asp.net empty website" in visual studio. From this point, what steps I will have to follow to add Sencha EXT JS for UI ?

If someone can please guide me step by step that would be really appreciable. I am really a newbies in sencha.

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you going to be using?

Comment: I will be using version 4.0. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create **two projects**: the **front-end** project with Sencha ExtJS and the **back-end** project with .NET.

- The back-end: create a new Web Site as a ASP.NET Web Service. Then create your Web Service and Web Methods:

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.myuri.org/")]
    [ScriptService]
    public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
        [WebMethod(Description = "Does something.")]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string MyMethod(string Something) ...
    }
```

- The front-end: create a new Sencha ExtJS application and connect your stores, requests, etc to your web services:

```
    new Ext.data.proxy.Ajax( {
        url: 'MyWebService.asmx/MyMethod',
        actionMethods: {
            create: 'POST',
            destroy: 'DELETE',
            read: 'POST',
            update: 'POST'
        }
    })
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Luz, thank you for your reply. I am not sure how this will work specially "create a new Web Site as a ASP.NET Web Service".

Comment: I would like to point out that while this answer is correct, the backend could also use ASP.NET WebAPI, available since ASP.NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

You may be best using Sencha CMD to generate a basic ExtJS web application structure in the empty web directory you are creating through Visual Studio.

Have a read of this http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/guide/getting_started-section-creating-an-application#

You will need to download and install Sencha CMD, and then use the generate command as shown in that doc link above.

Once complete, you can refresh and see the newly generate folder stubs in Visual Studio, e.g controllers, models, views, etc. It will generate an index.html file for you which if you launch and browse to from the local web server (VS) you should see a Hello message appear in an ExtJS basic UI.